# Jquery text link from tab to tab using WP UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hyperlink, tabs

I'm using a `jquery` tabs plugin for `Wordpress` (The plugin is downloadable at http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-ui/ )

I have a page with 4 tabs on it, and I want a text link to take people from tab 1 to tab 4.

I can add a text link to `#_enquire` which will take me to tab 4, but it also appends the url with #_enquire, so if you then click back to tab 1 and click the text link it no longer works since it's already at that URL.

I'm assuming there must be a relatively simple way to apply the same jquery used when you click the tab itself to a text link. Therefore when you click the text link it acts as if you clicked the tab name itself.

You can see the tabs on the site here: [thailand-golf-tours.com/golf-tours/bangkok/bangkok-2-days-golf-package/](http://thailand-golf-tours.com/golf-tours/bangkok/bangkok-2-days-golf-package/)

I've left the anchor version of the link on at the bottom of tab 1 ("Click here for tab 4")

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm used to using css/html so I'm not too great with javascript/jquery. I've tried contacting the plugin author through his site as well as the wordpress site and twitter and had no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than "redirecting" with your link, you need to simulate a click with jquery.

So clicking the text link is "the same as "clicking your fourth tab. As you did not post your code, I will post some code that should get the idea across.

```
jQuery("#the-name-of-the-link-id").on("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#the-name-of-the-tab-id").click();
});
```

This will simulate a tab click when you click the link!

**edit:**

try this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
    $("#the-name-of-the-link-id").on("click", function(e){ 
         e.preventDefault(); 
         e.stopPropagation(); 
         $("#the-name-of-the-tab-id").click(); 
    }); 
});
```

Again do NOT use the `href`. use an `id`, if you must use an `href` you do this selector `$('a[href="#_enquire"]')`, but that is a less straightforward way of doing it.

Comment: I tried adding it as a javascript in the page header with the name of the link id and tab id added in. I made the link itself "#" but when I clicked it, it just goes to the top of the page with a # at the end of the url :(

Comment: ok... you might need to add this:




$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#the-name-of-the-link-id").on("click", function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
     $("#the-name-of-the-tab-id").click();
  });
});


also, to be clear, the $('#id') is the Id of the respective links.


Edits added to the post. Again, make sure you prevent default, and then use the id's of the respective a tags.

Comment: `$` is not a global accessible jQuery object in WordPress. I made an edit, it should work now (not tested).

Comment: Nevermind - I had missed the bit about $('a[href="#_enquire"]')

THANKYOU SO MUCH! This has been doing my nut in!

Comment: then mark this as the correct answer if It helped you resolve your issue!